# Unable to select value from autocomplete textbox

Tags: selenium

I am writing test script in selenium web driver to select the option from auto complete text box but unable to select the option. below is the script that i have written so far.

```
public void autocomplete(){
        // Select city from the city auto suggestion text box
        String selectcity = "mumbai";
        WebElement select_city= driver.findElement(By.id("location"));
        select_city.sendKeys("mum");
        List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='suggestresult']"));
         for(WebElement option : optionsToSelect){
                System.out.println(option);
                if(option.getText().equals(selectcity)) {
                    option.click();
                    System.out.println("Trying to select: "+selectcity);
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

> Site URL is : http://talentrack.in/register and field is select city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wait for the drop down to appear before clicking on the desired item:

```java
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

driver.get("http://talentrack.in/register");

driver.findElement(By.id("location")).sendKeys("mum");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(
        "id('showsuggestion')//li[.='mumbai']"))).click();
```